# First Flask project - database file won't update

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I started learning Flask recently and the tutorial I'm following wants me to set up a To Do list application using sqlite3 as the database to store username, password, and the to do list itself. So far, I have my Schema and Models set up exactly like the tutorial, but my database file isn't updating. My tables show up in the database file, but they are empty. What am I doing wrong?

This is the schema:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('to_do_list.db', check_same_thread = False)
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute(
    """CREATE TABLE users(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        username VARCHAR(32),
        password VARCHAR(32)    
    );"""
)

connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Here is the signup model:

```
def signup(username, password):
connection = sqlite3.connect('to_do_list.db', check_same_thread = False)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute( """SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '{username}';""".format(username = username))
    exist = cursor.fetchone()

    if exist is None:
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO users(username, password)VALUES('{username}', '{password}');""".format(username = username, password = password))            
            
        connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()

    else:
        return ('User already exists!')
```

Here is the Flask routing:

```
@app.route('/signup', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        message = 'Please sign up!'
        return render_template('signup.html', message = message)
    else:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        return render_template('todo.html')
```

Comment: Where is the model code actually called?  That route function doesn't call it.

Comment: I added an answer, does this solve the issue?

Comment: Also, I see that the model and route function are both named `signup()`.  If they are in the same module, that could be a problem.

Comment: How do I call the model code? This step wasn't in the tutorial, and the tutorial code performs exactly as expected.

Comment: It seems like the function `def signup(username, password):`is in another file than the app.route function, it should be a problem however is not good design, you can call it watherver as long is understandable what it does, for instance (sign_up_validation or signup_check)

Comment: the routing, schema, and model are all separate .py files. I set it up that way as that is how the tutorial was setup. Should the model and routing be in the same .py file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to sleep on it and came up with the solution. The tutorial wasn't clear on some of the functions, and John Gordon's above comment helped me figure it out. I had to call model code in the route function. I also had to 'import model' since my models are in a different .py file.

The new routing:

```
@app.route('/signup', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        message = 'Please sign up!'
        return render_template('signup.html', message = message)
    else:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db = model.signup(username, password)
        return render_template('todo.html')
```

Thanks for your input everyone! Be healthy and safe, and happy holidays.

Answer (score 1):

here

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('to_do_list.db', check_same_thread = False)
curr = connection.cursor()

curr.execute(
    """CREATE TABLE users(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        username VARCHAR(32),
        password VARCHAR(32)    
    );"""
)

curr.commit()
curr.close()
```

You are adding the `commit()` function to the `connection` variable and not to the cursor.

> Edit, here too:

```
def signup(username, password):
connection = sqlite3.connect('to_do_list.db', check_same_thread = False)
    curr= connection.cursor()
    curr.execute( """SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '{username}';""".format(username = username))
    exist = curr.fetchone()

if exist is None:
    curr.execute("""INSERT INTO users(username, password)VALUES('{username}', '{password}');""".format(username = username, password = password))            
        
    curr.commit()
    curr.close()
    curr.close()

else:
    return ('User already exists!')
```

**IMPORTANT** if there is a `to_do_list.db` already created, after the editing of the script, remember to delete the file so it will create a new one.

Comment: I tried adding the commit() function to the cursor and got the following error: AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit'

Comment: Now that's strange.. I have change also in my answer the variable name, instead of cursor I call it curr (or db or anything else) because is the same name of the  function of sqlite3 .

Comment: I made the above changes and received the same error. It is still creating the database file with the tables, however. Strange. I will try running it to see if the database updates, at least.

Comment: Same issue, even with the above edits. My database won't update. I'll keep searching this site and messing around. If I get it to work I will update. Thanks for your help, just the same.

Comment: I'm sure you will eventually, what I sugest you is to start all over again, may be a typo somewhere or something you missing